# how to know CVE affects which Jar/artifact?

Tags: vulnerability, java, vulnerability-scanners, cve

When I'm trying to analyze CVEs to detect which jars are affected by the CVE, I getting confused.
Let's take as an example this CVE: CVE-2022-22978

In the description:

> "In Spring Security versions 5.5.6 and 5.6.3 and older unsupported versions, RegexRequestMatcher can easily be misconfigured to be bypassed on some servlet containers. Applications using RegexRequestMatcher with `.` in the regular expression are possibly vulnerable to an authorization bypass"

They don't state which jar or artifact, they only say Spring security, and when searching for spring security there are several artifacts, like `spring-security-core` and `spring-security-web`.

Adding another example: CVE-2019-3774

Description:

> "Spring Batch versions 3.0.9, 4.0.1, 4.1.0, and older unsupported versions, were susceptible to XML External Entity Injection (XXE) when receiving XML data from untrusted sources."

When searching for spring batch there are 2 artifacts, `spring-batch-core` and `spring-batch-infrastructure`.

How do I know which one is vulnerable?

Comment: In both cases the two mentioned libraries have the same version structure and release dates so most likely they belong together. So in doubt I would say update both libraries for spring-security and spring-batch. https://mvnrepository.com shows the vulnerabilities in the each `core` library only (but I don't know how reliable this info is and what source they use).

Comment: but for the cve CVE-2022-22978,  it is mentioned for the `spring-security-core` as direct vulnerability here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/5.5.3 and for `spring-security-web` it is mentioned as vulnerability from dependency  here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/5.4.3